# linked lists adding elements combining front and back positions

Tags: java

I am programming an implementation of a Linked List in Java. I have two methods, one that puts the elements in front of the list:

```
public void addFront(int n){
        Node temp=new Node(n);
        if (llist==null){
            first=temp;
        }
        else{
            llist.next=temp;
        }
        llist=temp;
    }
```

So if I add elements in my list like:

```
l1.addFront(1)
l1.addFront(2)
l1.addFront(3)
```

It will print: 1, 2, and 3

Now I have other method that puts the elements by behind, like this:

```
public void addBack(int n){
        Node temp=new Node(n);
        temp.next=llist;
        llist=temp;
        first=temp;
    }
```

So if I add the elements like:

```
l1.addBack(4)
l1.addBack(5)
l1.addBack(6)
```

it will print 6,5,4; all is fine until here; the problem is when I want to do the following line with the last list:

```
l1.addFront(9)
```

it only prints 9 and 6, but the other numbers get lost, why is that?

the printing method I have is this:

```
public void print(){
        Node curr=first;
        while(curr!=null){
            System.out.println(curr.e);
            curr=curr.next;
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: If you iterate through the linked-list from the front when printing it (I assume you are), the output of the first is supposed to be 3, 2, 1 and the output of the second is supposed to be 4, 5, 6. Consider that if you add 2 **in front of** 1, it's supposed to print 2 **before** 1.

Comment: @Dukeling no it is the opposite, check the added print code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method names are causing a bit of confusion, as `addBack` is adding to the beginning of the list (and appears to do so correctly), and you apparently intend `addFront` should add to the end of the list.

Your code for `addFront` is in fact always adding the new node as either the first and only element or as the second element, replacing anything there.

To add at the end, you need to traverse the list to find the last element (i.e., the one with `next == null`) and set the new item to be next, replacing the `null`.

Or as it may be from your code fragments, you intend for `llist` to be the last element in the list, you need to maintain it in that state, and use it instead of traversing as I described above.

Based on the assumption that you really want the methods to act as described above (though it seems backward), and the assumption that you do want to maintain the `llist` field holding onto the last element so that you don't need to traverse the list for adds to the end, the following code should do it.

```
public void addFront(int n){
    Node temp=new Node(n);
    if (llist==null){
        first=temp;
    }
    else{
        llist.next=temp;
    }
    llist=temp;
}

public void addBack(int n){
    Node temp=new Node(n);
    temp.next=first;
    first=temp;
    if (llist == null)
        llist = first;
}
```

Comment: Actually, that line is only to allow for initializing `llist` if addBack is the first call.